# Use Google apps in the emulator

Tags: android

Would it be possible to provide a emulator image that has all the `Google apps` that come with real devices, like `Gmail` etc?

I don't have access to a 2.0 device which makes it close to impossible for me to develop/debug apps which uses `AccountManager` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the Android Dev Phone system image from http://developer.htc.com/adp.html.

Then, create a new AVD (using the `android` tool or `adb`) with the matching version. The avd directory will appear at the `.android` directory inside your home directory (Run `%USERPROFILE%` on windows). Then, put `system.img` file downloaded into the `<name of avd>.avd` directory. Start the emulator and you will use Android with Google apps installed.

**Disclaimer**: about whether it is legal or not to download and use such images, I don't know. Please read the text there and decide yourself.

Comment: Wow thanks! I didn't think the dev image had the Google applications. It even has paid market. Thanks!

Comment: Only bad thing is that there is no ADP image for 2.0 yet, if there ever will be.

Answer (score 0):

Given the trouble that Cyanogenmod had with trying to redistribute Google's apps, I would say it's not an option.  However, if it's something in the Android source (like the calendar), you can compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to debug the app, you don't need to create a new image.  You can run some of the google apps including gmail and google maps in the emulator.  If you go to the  Android SDK and AVD manager in the Eclipse Android plugin, and then go to "available packages", for every SDK there are two downloads for each version of the api.  There is the one with Google Apps and one with out.  The one with Google apps has apps such as gmail and google maps.  It does not have all Google apps.  The market is not there for instance .

Comment: That only includes Maps, not Gmail.

Comment: When I run google apps in the emulator, I see gmail.  I can even log into my gmail account.  I tried it in the 1.5 emulator and the 1.6 emulator.  It works in both.